# r -- finding difference between business days

Tags: r

I have several years of data (only for business days (no weekends or holidays)) in an [r]  data frame and would like to find the difference between the data on the 2nd and 5th business day of each month.  So the solution needs to go thru the list, determine the 2nd and 5th business day, get the data **and the full date** for the corresponding dates and then  find the difference.

the data looks like:

```
1/19/1990  1.22

1/20/1990  1.25

1/23/1990  1.26   ## (Gap in date is weekend)

...

2/1/1990   1.34

2/2/1990   1.36

2/5/1990   1.22   ## (Gap in date is weekend)
```

I have tried using dateTime() but it doesn't handicap for weekends and holidays. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Honestly, I just understood the question when I read Dirk's answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38448310/r-finding-difference-in-business-days/38448463#38448463

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that by the 2nd and 5th business day you mean that 2nd and 5th day of data that is actually present in the data for each month.  If that is the question then its as follows.  We read in the data and convert the first column to `"Date"` class.  Then we aggregate the data by month taking the required difference.

```
Lines <- "1/19/1990 1.22
1/20/1990 1.25
1/23/1990 1.26 
1/24/1990 1.26 
1/25/1990 1.26 
1/26/1990 1.26 
2/1/1990 1.34
2/2/1990 1.36
2/5/1990 1.22 
2/6/1990 1.22 
2/7/1990 1.22 
2/8/1990 1.22"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines, col.names = c("Date", "Value"))
DF$Date <- as.Date(DF$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
aggregate(DF$Value, list(ym = format(DF$Date, "%Y-%m")), 
   function(x) if (length(x) >= 5) x[5] - x[2] else NA)
```

Using zoo and chron it can be done entirely via `read.zoo`:

```
library(zoo)
library(chron)
read.zoo(text = Lines, FUN = chron, FUN2 = as.yearmon, 
  aggregate =  function(x) if (length(x) >= 5) x[5] - x[2] else NA)
```

**Update**  Since this was first written the `text=` argument to `read.table` and `read.zoo` was added in R and the answer has been updated to use this.

Answer (score 15):

The basic `Date` type works for calendar days, but not for business days. You need extra logic to take care of business days.  I am aware of two efforts:

1. the [timeDate](http://cran.r-project.org/package=timeDate) package which is part of rMetrics has a number of calendars
2. my [RQuantLib](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RQuantLib) package can do so too by relying in the logic from [QuantLib](http://www.quantlib.org)

Here is just two examples from RQuantLib, there are a number of related other functions:

```
R>        from <- as.Date("2009-04-07")
R>        to <-as.Date("2009-04-14")
R>        getHolidayList("UnitedStates", from, to)
NULL
R>        to <- as.Date("2009-10-7")
R>        getHolidayList("UnitedStates", from, to)
[1] "2009-05-25" "2009-07-03" "2009-09-07"
R>
```

and

```
R>        from <- as.Date("2009-04-07")
R>        to<-as.Date("2009-04-14")
R>        businessDaysBetween("UnitedStates", from, to)
[1] 5
R>
```

Comment: I think it should be noted that "business day" is not super well defined outside of a particular domain. For instance, many government offices are closed on Columbus day, but the New York Stock Exchange is not.

Comment: You can pick which "calendar" you need:  UnitedStates, UnitedStates/Settlement, UnitedStates/NYSE, UnitedStates/GovernmentBond, UnitedStates/NERC and WeekendsOnly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little function that lets you input a start date, end date and a vector of dates that correspond to holidays (useful if you are using a non standard holiday calendar) and returns the number of working days between them, counting both the start and end date

```
workdays = function(iniDate, endDate, holidays) {
  theDates = seq(from=iniDate,to=endDate,by="day")
  isHoliday = theDates %in% holidays
  isWeekend = (as.POSIXlt(theDates)$wday) %in% (c(0,6))
  return (sum(!isHoliday & !isWeekend))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find the difference between business days using the package [`bizdays`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bizdays/index.html), but you must have a list of holidays (nonworking days) and that's not your case. Anyway I think it can help others.

With bizdays the following code would compute the amount of business days between 2 dates.

```
library(bizdays)
cal <- Calendar(holidaysANBIMA, weekdays=c('sunday', 'saturday'), dib=252)
from_dates <- c('2013-07-12', '2012-06-13')
to_dates <- seq(as.Date('2014-02-17'), as.Date('2016-07-21'), by='months')
bizdays(from_dates, to_dates, cal = cal)

##  [1]  153  442  194  483  234  526  276  570  321  613  364  655  404  695
## [15]  446  735  486  779  529  822  571  863  614  904  654  946  695  987
## [29]  738 1029
```

EDIT:

Since version 1.0.0 bizdays comes with a few built in calendars

```
library(bizdays)
from_dates <- c('2013-07-12', '2012-06-13')
to_dates <- seq(as.Date('2014-02-17'), as.Date('2016-07-21'), by='months')
bizdays(from_dates, to_dates, cal = "Brazil/ANBIMA")
```

The `Calendar` function will be deprecated.